# How to run toad properly with oci.dll

Tags: oracle, toad

Toad Version: 12.8.0.49
InstaClient Version: 12.2 , 19.5

I tried with both version of Instaclient but Toad throw error -> Can not load oci.dll even if the file exists in the location

Answer (score 0):

Your oracle instant client and toad must have the same bitness (both 32bits or both 64bits), otherwise it won't work.

If this is already the case, use process monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find what's missing (filter on process name contains toad). I think you'll find something like "msvcr120.dll NAME_NOT_FOUND" => then go download it on microsoft.com (package redistributable for visual studio).
Had the same issue, installing the 2013 package solved it.